# How to change Rails 3 server default port in develoment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my development machine, I use port 10524. So I start my server this way :

```
rails s -p 10524
```

Is there a way to change the default port to 10524 so I wouldn't have to append the port each time I start the server?

Comment: simple answer is edit `config/puma.rb` if running default puma server

Answer (score 137, accepted):

First - do not edit anything in your gem path! It will influence all projects, and you will have a lot problems later...

In your project edit `script/rails` this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)

# THIS IS NEW:
require "rails/commands/server"
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({
        :Port        => 10524,
        :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
        :daemonize   => false,
        :debugger    => false,
        :pid         => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
        :config      => File.expand_path("config.ru")
      })
    end
  end
end
# END OF CHANGE
require 'rails/commands'
```

The principle is simple - you are monkey-patching the server runner - so it will influence just one project.

**UPDATE**: Yes, I know that the there is simpler solution with bash script containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
rails server -p 10524
```

but this solution has a serious drawback - it is boring as hell.

Comment: Or even an alias! `alias rs='rails server -p 10524'`

Comment: Be sure to put the `require 'rails/commands'` AFTER the new stuff you paste in. Otherwise it will still try port 3000.

Comment: doesn't work for me, still starts at :3000. Howver @Spencer solution  (on this page) works

Comment: Worked in one instance for me but not another. When I had to create my own script folder and rails file -> not great success. Probably has to do with whether or not rails is running off of the script or not?

Comment: @trisweb Could you explain how to create `alias rs`

Comment: @Selvamani in the shell window, run `alias rs='rails server -p 10524'`.

After that, you'll be able to type `rs` in that shell to perform the full command. You may want to make this alias permanent by adding it to `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 131):

I like to append the following to `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  class Server
    alias :default_options_alias :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_alias.merge!(:Port => 3333)
    end    
  end
end
```

Comment: Use `super` instead of alias hack.

Comment: Unfortunately, if `super` is used instead of alias, it calls the wrong method. It calls the `::Rack::Server` version of default_options.

Comment: With ruby 2.0 you could `prepend` an anonymous module instead of using `alias`.  This allows a clean use of `super`.

Comment: This answer will cause `Rails::Server` to become defined in contexts when it shouldn't be (e.g. running the Rails console). So I recommend putting the code at the end of `application.rb`, guarded with an `if defined?(Rails::Server)`.

Answer (score 30):

One more idea for you. Create a rake task that calls rails server with the -p.

```
task "start" => :environment do
  system 'rails server -p 3001'
end
```

then call `rake start` instead of `rails server`

Answer (score 17):

Combining two previous answers, for Rails 4.0.4 (and up, presumably), this suffices at the end of `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({Port: 10524})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I retrieve this option in the running app? Specifically, I want to set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`, otherwise it's still pointing to port 3000.

Comment: I added a question related to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431315/actionmailers-default-url-options-how-to-retrieve-port-automatically-from-defa

Answer (score 10):

We're using Puma as a web server, and [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to set environment variables in development. This means I can set an environment variable for `PORT`, and reference it in the Puma config.

```
# .env
PORT=10524


# config/puma.rb
port ENV['PORT']
```

However, you'll have to start your app with `foreman start` instead of `rails s`, otherwise the puma config doesn't get read properly.

I like this approach because the configuration works the same way in development and production, you just change the value of the port if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Radek and Spencer...
On Rails 4(.0.2 - Ruby 2.1.0 ), I was able to append this to *config/boot.rb*:

```
# config/boot.rb

# ...existing code

require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  # Override default development
  # Server port
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge(Port: 3100)
    end
  end
end
```

All other configuration in [default_options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Server.html#method-i-default_options) are still set, and command-line switches still override defaults.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Rails 2.3 - `script/server`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rack/handler'
module Rack::Handler
  class << WEBrick
    alias_method :old_run, :run
  end

  class WEBrick
    def self.run(app, options={})
      options[:Port] = 3010 if options[:Port] == 3000
      old_run(app, options)
    end
  end
end

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/server'
```

Comment: Thanks! I came here looking for a solution with rails 2.3.18 :-)

Comment: I did have to move the `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'` before `require 'rack/handler'` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using puma (I'm using this on Rails 6+):

To change default port for all environments:

The "{3000}" part sets the default port if undefined in ENV.

```
~/config/puma.rb

change:
    port ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }
for:
    port ENV.fetch('PORT') { 10524 }
```

To define it depending on the environment, using Figaro gem for credentials/environment variable:

```
~/application.yml
local_db_username: your_user_name
​local_db_password: your_password
PORT: 10524
```

You can adapt this to you own environment variable manager.

Answer (score 2):

For ruby > 3 and For rails > 7

in file app/config/puma.rb, update the port number.

```
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3200 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install `$ gem install foreman`, and use foreman to start your server as defined in your `Procfile` like:

```
web: bundle exec rails -p 10524
```

You can check `foreman` gem docs here: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman for more info

The benefit of this approach is not only can you set/change the port in the config easily and that it doesn't require much code to be added but also you can add different steps in the `Procfile` that foreman will run for you so you don't have to go though them each time you want to start you application something like:

```
bundle: bundle install
web: bundle exec rails -p 10524
...
...
```

Cheers