# How to start WEBrick in a different port than 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

```
[2011-09-11 06:14:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=32723 port=3000
```

How to start WEBrick in a different port than 3000, is there a way to specify this information in a config file instead of the command line argument ("-p")

Comment: I haven't seen a config file for WEBric. But you can always create small script that starts the server on the port you want and check the script in your source control repository.

Comment: Check this out http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html

Comment: Please check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment

Answer (score 26):

Use `-p` parameter

For Rails 2

```
ruby script/server -p3001
```

and for w/o command line  ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment)

EDITED For Rails 3

```
rails s -p3001
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to run on port 3001, add this bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 rails server -p 3001
```

Comment: Whoops! Missed that part. Changed.