# How to set default port for Webrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I want to set the default port when I do

```
rails s
```

to 3010, instead of having to say:

```
rails s -p 3010
```

...every time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the `Port` by adding the following code to `config/boot.rb`

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    alias :default_options_alias :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_alias.merge!(:Port => 3010)
    end    
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (using Eclipse/Aptana). The port is still 3000 after starting the server.

Comment: FWIW, Rails 4.2 and higher now default to binding only to localhost instead of all interfaces. You can use `default_options_alias.merge!(:Host => '0.0.0.0')` in the above example to restore the former functionality if you need to access WEBrick from an outside machine.

Comment: More info on this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment , especially the use of `super.merge({Port: 3010})` instead of the alias merge line.  Both versions are working for me under Rails 4.2.11.3, Ruby 2.2.3.