# Installing nginx on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-ec2

I need to install Nginx on Amazon EC2. However, a rails server is already running on port 80.

I need to:

- See what server is running
- Figure out how to stop it
- Figure out how to start nginx on port 80 instead of that server.

Any help?

Comment: Is Apache possibly running?  You could try ```service apache2 stop```

Comment: Maybe. I get this error:  * Stopping web server apache2                                                                                                       ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

Comment: With sudo it worked. But I cannot start it again: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: I don't know how your server is setup.  You have to bee root to stop Apache.  So you could try ```sudo service apache2 stop``` if you're running debian.

Comment: This is Ubuntu in Amazon EC2.  sudo service apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2             

If I try sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                       (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Try running ```ps -e``` to see all running processes and look for something along the lines of apache, httpd, or nginx.

Comment: Here are what seems suspicious:
deployer  5072     1  0 11:06 ?        00:00:05 Rack: /home/deployer/www/yyyy/current 
root     14374     1  0 Aug21 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
nobody   14375 14374  0 Aug21 ?        00:00:40 nginx: worker process
deployer 16255     1  0 Aug21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: With that information I don't know too much about nginx and if you're sure you don't need these servers you can try using the ```kill``` command for example ```sudo kill 14374``` where the number is the process id.  You can also check /etc/init.d for scripts that load on startup and see what you can find there.

Comment: what I really want is to restart those services. I want to change nginx configuration and restart it. But I get this error: 
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: Try using ```netstat``` to see what program is binding to port 80.

Comment: I suspect that Apache is using port 80. that's why nginx doesnt restart. But, why is my nginx process running then?

Comment: just netstat? i dont see the port there

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14374/nginx

Comment: I stop it but it is still listening:
ubuntu@ip-10-176-142-49:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
Stopping nginx: nginx.
ubuntu@ip-10-176-142-49:~$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep ':80 '
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14374/nginx

Comment: Sorry, may have given you bad advice I just found you can try ```lsof -i:80``` this will give you all processes bound to port 80.

Comment: Looks like it didn't terminate properly ```kill 14374``` will end the process.  You should be able to restart it afterwards.

Comment: Seems to work. I killed it, now I am able to start/stop. Thanks. Now I will check if I can configure it.

Comment: one question, I should be using nginx or apache, right? Not both

Comment: It seems that the Nginx that is running now is different from the one that was running before (using different .conf file). How can I check what nginx is executed on startup?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to check which one is loaded but you can use ```/usr/bin/nginx -c /path/to/config``` to load in a specific configuration.  I think ```-g``` will set that to default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did ps -ef and found nginx process.
After that I made sudo kill  , and started nginx again

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

*Run Rails on a different port*

If you want to run Rails and NGinX on the same server, you can first configure rails to run on a different port and then setup NGinX:

[How to change Rails 3 server default port in develoment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment)

You can have NGinX forward HTTP requests to the new port you select for Rails

**Option 2**

*Use a separate instance*

You can alternatively use a separate instance for NGinX.  Depending on your traffic, a Micro instance may be sufficient for that purpose.

Generally I would suggest running the load balancer on a different instance.