# Rails - How do I configure thin's port and environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I've installed the thin gem for a rails app, but I'm unable to find a configuration file.  Does installing the gem mean that I've installed the server?  I just want to start Thin with a different port than 3000 and in production mode.  The server is Windows.  Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify it as such.

```
rails server -e production -p 4000
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server

Comment: That works, but is there a way to embed those commands somewhere so it runs like that with a simple `rails server` command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment