# Rake commands not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

**UPDATE:**

So it turns out the issue is has to do with me corrupting confg/boot.rb.  Details are in the answer below.

---

So basically rake stopped working.  I'm trying to add a new model, and if I then run

`rake db:migrate`

I get:

`Error: Command 'db:migrate' not recognized`

I'm pretty sure rake is correctly installed and sourced though.  If I run:

`rake`

I get the normal 'man' page starting with

`Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]...The most common rails commands are...`

Interestingly enough it also spits this out at the bottom:

`.../db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run 'rake db:migrate' to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter .../config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.`

I do intend to use a database, so I'd love to get rake working...

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Are you sure you are not mistaking the commands `rails` and `rake`? What's the output of `which rake`?

Comment: try rake db:create, no schema means no data.

Comment: @mechanicalfish `which rake` returns `<root>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake`

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson `rake db:create` gives me `Error: Command 'db:create' not recognized`

Comment: @cjhin This is weird. Come to the [rails chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails) I'll try to help you.

Comment: @mechanicalfish ah... apparently I don't have a high enough reputation to talk in the chat room?

Comment: This may sound daft..But have you done a `bundle install` then tried a `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue is due to me incorrectly following instructions on a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment) regarding changing the port that `rails server` binds to.

Basically I incorrectly modified config/boot.rb which somehow corrupted the behavior of `rake`.

Specifically I completely misread and mashed together the top two answers, appending the following code to config/boot.rb instead of placing it in a standalone script.

```
# THIS IS NEW:
require "rails/commands/server"
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({
        :Port        => 10524,
        :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
        :daemonize   => false,
        :debugger    => false,
        :pid         => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
        :config      => File.expand_path("config.ru")
      })
    end
  end
end
# END OF CHANGE
require 'rails/commands'
```

Sorry guys.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Hey @cjhin I just did the same thing. How'd you fix it?

Comment: @j0e  When you say "the same thing", do you mean the same issue with incorrectly modifying config/boot.rb?

Comment: Yes. I needed to set my server into using port 9999 by default for some testing and it borked my rake command. I editing the boot.rb back to what it was before but it's still messed up. How'd you fix yours?

Comment: honestly I think I just created a new rails app and ported over the data I needed... sorry that's probably not the answer you were hoping for

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it via bundle?

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the `Error: Command 'db:migrate' not recognized`.  Thanks though!

Comment: I added it to the original post, hope that helps!