# Can not access production env rails app running local on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, production-environment

I can run my rails app fine in developemnt using:

`rails s` then going to localhost:3000

However, I need to test production and tried

`rails s -e production`, however, when I go to localhost:3000, I see nothing happen in my rails server.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Set localhost 3000 as the default_url_option ----
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Why can't I access my production rails app?  Is there any specific tutorial on how to run a production env on a local machine? I am using Mac OSX High Sierra.

Comment: On the browser, do you get an error? How do know 'see' that nothing happens on your rails server?

Comment: Noting is outputted to the terminal I started the server on

Comment: Haven’t used rails in a while, maybe in production mode only the errors are logged? What is the result in the browser wen you try to access the server url?

Comment: what about `rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4.2 Server port forwarding on Vagrant does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799260/rails-4-2-server-port-forwarding-on-vagrant-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe rails logs requests to the console in production like it does in development, so you shouldn't see anything happen.

Try running `rake assets:precompile` before starting the server. Also, make sure you have created a database for your production environment, and that you have migrated. You can create the database like so: `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`, then just migrate like this `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

If you are still having issues getting your application to run in production, check the production log.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue, in my case I was building small API application. And didnt have a route for /. Checking log/production.log helped me figuring out whats wrong, since production environment doesnt write anything in console.