# Bind rails server to 127.0.0.1 by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'd like to bind the rails server to 127.0.0.1, instead of 0.0.0.0 so its not accessible when I'm working from coffee shops.

Is there a configuration file where I can specify this option so I don't have to pass the command line switch:

```
rails server -b 127.0.0.1
```

?

Comment: For rails 5 this worked for me unlike answers below:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33852354/520567

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are searching for **Rails 5**:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33852354/2552259)

---

In `Rails ~> 4.0` you can customize the boot section of the Server class:

In `/config/boot.rb` add this lines:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({Port: 10524, Host: '127.0.0.1'})
    end
  end
end
```

As already answered on this questions:

[How to change Rails 3 server default port in develoment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment)

[How to change the default binding ip of Rails 4.2 development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server)

Comment: The question is for the bound IP, not the port. I'm sure the config could be in the same file but it would be useful to specify the IP part here.

Comment: Added the Host parameter.

Comment: This file is checked into version control, though, right? If the value is set here, then it's set in production as well.

Comment: Actually I don't know, but I assume you can set an 'if Rails.env...' in the file. Never tryed.

Comment: This not valid in rails 5 anymore. This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33852354/520567

Comment: Updated the answer to include the link to rails 5 solution. Even with this question specifically tagging rails 4 might be useful.

Comment: This didn't work for me, instead of that i modified `config/puma.rb`, which is referred within https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24435

Answer (score 4):

You can make a bash script to just run the command by default:

```
#!/bin/bash
rails server -b 127.0.0.1
```

Put it in the same folder as your project, name it anything you want (e.g. `devserv`), then

```
chmod +x devserv
```

And all you have to do is `./devserv`

Answer (score 3):

I use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) as a process manager in development.

After adding `gem 'foreman'` to your Gemfile and running `bundle install`, create a file `Procfile` in the root of your application directory.

While you can add lines to manage other processes, mine just reads:

```
web: rails server -p $PORT -b 127.0.0.1
```

Then, to start the Rails server via the Procfile, run `foreman start`. If you have other processes here (Redis, workers) they'll boot at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using puma, there are several ways:

1. In `config/puma.rb`, add this:

```rb
bind 'tcp://localhost:3001'
```

However, this would cause puma to listen to two ports or more.

2. In `config/puma.rb`, add this:

```rb
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }, 'localhost'
```

3. If you do not wish to sabotage your puma file, try modifying puma's default configuration in `<puma_gem_path>/lib/puma/configuration.rb`, and do this:

```rb
DefaultTCPHost = 'localhost'
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/configuration.rb#L12)

Answer (score 0):

**If you put the default options on `config/boot.rb` then all command attributes for rake and rails fails (example: `rake -T` or `rails g model user`)!** So, append this to `bin/rails` after line `require_relative '../config/boot'` and the code is executed only for the rails server command:

```
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '127.0.0.1', Port: 10524)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `bin/rails` file loks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'

# Set default host and port to rails server
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '127.0.0.1', Port: 10524)
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'rails/commands'
```