# Run Rails server with different port on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

i need to run Rails server on Ubuntu machine with different port number(`i.e-8888`) for all time.So please help me what should the correct command to run this server.I am using Rails version 4.2.0 and i want to run this server for ever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Rails 3 server default port in develoment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842818/how-to-change-rails-3-server-default-port-in-develoment)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `-p` option to specify the port number:

```
rails server -p 8888
```

You can even make an alias: `rails s='rails server -p 8888'` and put it in the `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` so that every time you run `rails server` it will use port 8888